# SED - remove attribute from HTML tag

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I want to remove a specific attribute(name in my example) from the HTML tag, that might be in different positions for each line in my file

Example Input:

```html
<img name="something_random_for_each_tag" src="https://websiteurl.com/286.jpg" alt="img">
```

Expected output:

```html
<img src="https://websiteurl.com/286.jpg" alt="img">
```

My code:

```sh
sed 's/name=".*"//g' <<< '<img name="something_random_for_each_tag" src="https://websiteurl.com/286.jpg" alt="img">'
```

but it only shows `<img >`, I am losing src attribute as well

Notes:

1. name attribute might be in any position in a tag (not necessarily at the beginning)
2. you can use sed, awk, Perl, or anything you like, it should work on the command line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sed` expression matches the text up to the last `"` in the line. It must have been

```
sed 's/ name="[^"]*"//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/^<img/ && match($0,/src.*/){print substr($0,1,4),substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** Using `sub`(substitute function) of `awk`.

```
awk '/^<img/{sub(/name="[^"]*" /,"")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

***1st solution:*** Using match function of `awk` to match from src till last of line and printing 1st 4 characters with space with matched regex value.

***2nd solution:*** Checking condition if line starts from `<img` then substitute name=" till again `"` comes with NULL and printing current line.